# Adding Image in readme.txt file of wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, readme

It is possible to add a gif file in the readme.txt file of wordpress plugin in the wordpress.org plugin repository?

My plugin url is https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-toggle-comments-form-fields/

I don't want the image in the screeshot section  - I need the image in the description section.

I know that i can insert a video but in my plugin a little gif will be ok...

Comment: Erez, please use proper upper and lower case characters - this is no chat and questions serve as reference for later visitors as well. Also: Are you talking about the wordpress.org plugin repository? Have you already tried it? If yes: Then how? Show us with an [edit] to your question, please.

Answer (score 1):

While I cannot remember on top of my head live example of plugin with a gif, there are quite a few with videos and at least ones using animated PNG as header ([AJAX Comment Loading](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-comment-loading/)).

So I would say — yes you can, but no guarantee it will end up well. It's not explicitly forbidden or allowed either. :) Might be better to load gif from plugin too (like screenshots) and not as external resource.

Answer (score 1):

**Rarst** - Thanks for your answer.

I found that you can't add image at all to the **description** tab, you can add only video from youtube, vimeo or wordpress in this tab.

You can add a jpg , png or gif (animated gif too) to the **screenshoot** section or to the banner that appear in head of plugin page.

In other words you can add any type of images to files that go to **assets folder** that its means screenshoots, banners and etc.

In my case:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-toggle-comments-form-fields/
I added a youtube to the description tab and a animated gif to the screenshots tab