# How can I view my readme.txt file to include inline images, videos...prior to submitting a New Plugin for review by wordpress.org?

Tags: offline, readme

I am a newbie and am likely asking for too much but here it is,
I have written my first plugin and created a readme.txt file and tested it with the validator and it passes with flying colors.

I have read the posted question [Adding Image in readme.txt file of wordpress plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166938/adding-image-in-readme-txt-file-of-wordpress-plugin) and it does not show the markdown syntax.

I feel a little uneasy about submitting the plugin to wordpress.org because I'm confused about referencing inline images and videos within the markdown syntax.  The documentation does not specify if the images are located within the repository at a relative path or are they assumed to be in the assets directory (no path needed just the filename) or if you can indicate a url to a different server where the image can reside.

Example taken from daringfireball.net markdown syntax:

```
![Alt text](/path/to/img.jpg "Optional title")
```

If I specified the following in my readme.txt

```
![Alt text](http://myserver.com/images/img.jpg "My title")
```

the validator at https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/validator/ does not show any indication that an image is referenced and displays no error.

Alternatly if the image being referenced is in the assets folder of my plugin how do I reference it?

```
![Alt text](/assets/img.jpg "My title")
```

I read that markdown also supports inline videos is this true?
If so what is the syntax?

Finally it would be cool if there was a way to view the readme.txt file exactly how it would appear in the repository before submitting it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit a plugin to WordPress.org, you need to put everything in a zip file that you must put on your server. After validate it, you receive a mail with the new svn link for the validated plugin.

Readme.txt link all images to à folder called `assets` where banner, screenshots, logo take place.

For the validation, you can reproduce the folder structure in your zip, as it will be in the svn :

```
 Svn plugin folder
       ----- assets
              --- banner-772-250.png
              --- screenshot-001.png
              --- icon-128x128.png

       ----- trunk 
              --- readme.txt
              --- plugin_main.php
              --- includes
               .....

      ----- tags
              --- 1.0
```

When online, visitors will see the readme.txt from the trunk folder, the header line 'Stable tag' will redirect user to right current version (tags/1.0 or trunk) and generate the zip file for the download.

You can embed video from youtube with the markdown [youtube https://youtu.be.....].

An image markdown for image look like this for me:
    1. The screenshot description corresponds to screenshot-1.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif).

What you will do, will always be under control, try and you'll be able to remove, modify everything on your svn directly.

You will find on the web, a lot readme.txt validator website. I use [generatewp.com](https://generatewp.com/plugin-readme/) to create it quickly.

You can read the WordPress documentation about readme.txt : [How the readme.txt works](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/how-your-readme-txt-works/), the page explain how the file is parsed and a brief explain of the markdown.

You can also read the developper [Plugin Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/), the WordPress.org part, talks about svn, readme.txt, asset and update [Plugin Handbook WordPress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/)
Hope it helps.

Comment: Hope your plugin will be available soon ! Don't forget to mark the answer as resolved ;-)

Comment: Very helpful Benoti, in the youtube example is there a link to documentation showing all possible shortcode used in markdown? For example can I use responsive code:
    [div style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden;"][youtube style="border: 4px solid red; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zGsmV-xBk6s?rel=0&iv_load_policy=3"][/youtube][div]

Comment: I really don't think, I'll add some links to my answer soon.